# Извлечение данных из веб-страниц с помощью машинного обучения

Tags: javascript, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Делаю расширение для браузера chrome, которое будет выявлять (предсказывать) однотипные элементы для извлечения в файл, после того как пользователь указал один или несколько элементов на странице.
То есть есть html-страница, пользователь выбирает элемент на странице, далее необходимо предложить (предсказать) похожие элементы на этой же странице. И выделить их цветом. Если все подходит можно извлечь данные из страницы.
Если предложенные элементы не подходят пользователю, он выделяет новый элемент для уточнения выборки.
Я в машинном обучение читал про различные методы и алгоритмы, но полноценного осознания нет.

Я склоняюсь к такому решению: 
1) Использовать обучение без учителя, чтобы изучить структуру входных данных (html-страница) и разбить элементы страницы на кластеры. Так как html-страница - это не маркированные данные. (Кластеризация)
2) Потом обучение с учителем, чтобы узнать к какому кластеру соответствует выбранный пользователем элемент. (Классификация)
3) Далее найти все элементы, соответствующие данному кластеру и показать их пользователю (создать цветную рамку вокруг элементов на странице).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кокой тип машинного обучения и его метод более всего подходят под данную задачу.
И я никак не могу понять как лучше представить html-страницу в виде входного набора данных (data set).

Может быть мне стоит использовать библиотеку TensorFlow.js ?

Comment: А что вы вкладываете в понятие *похожие* элементы?

Comment: Похожие элементы, которые имеют примерно одинаковую структуру. Например, есть тег <div>, который содержит несколько <p> и в конце div'a <time>. А соседний элемент на странице <div> также содержит несколько <p>, но в нем уже нет time. "Похожие" в этом смысле.

Comment: Я, конечно, не специалист по машинному обучению, но для обучения нужны четкие критерии. На какой вход должен быть какой выход. А иначе вы не сможете обучить.